# Getting remaining time to charge the battery fully in WMI C#

Tags: c#, wmi

I used **Win32_Battery** [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074(v=vs.85).aspx) with C# to get the remaining time to charge the battery in minutes. But it didn't work for me.

**Edit: No exception just null value returned.**
[image]

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Battery"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_Battery instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("TimeToFullCharge: {0}", queryObj["TimeToFullCharge"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to create immediatly `ManagementClass` using [ManagmentPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wzwcace(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)? What doesn't work in your code? Can you give a exception?

Comment: Sadly no exceptions :( just return null value.